# ES6 Class and module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am seeing this pattern these days for nodeJS implementation, where in we have the following code for my Module:

```
class Foo {
  bar() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}
module.exports = Foo;
```

Then when I do a require and finally say new to create an instance of the class.

```
var Foo = require(./foo);
var myFoo = new Foo();
myFoo.bar();
```

This pattern according to me will keep creating multiple instances of class Foo, everytime it is called.

The other pattern could have been what i am used to where in my foo.js would be.

```
module.exports = {
  bar: function() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
};
```

And then i just require and call bar.

```
var foo = require(./foo);
foo.bar();
```

Question would these two behave the same? Will the second pattern keep creating objects everytime I require and call bar on the object?

Isn't creating singleton pattern a good idea in case 1 as we are used to in other languages, wherein we keep serving the same instance if it has already been created once?

Comment: you are using ES6 so be sure that, very few browser support this feature.

Comment: The intention is to run in nodeJS and not in browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This pattern according to me will keep creating multiple instances of class Foo, everytime it is called.

Yes, that's the purpose. Though `new Foo();` is only executed once in your example as well.

> would these two behave the same?

No.

> Will the second pattern keep creating objects everytime I require and call bar on the object?

No. `require()` calls are cached, they return the same module every time.

> Isn't creating singleton pattern a good idea?

No, a singleton is rarely a good idea if it contains any state. Your example does not, but where `class`es are used in Node.js they usually do.